# Personalizar caracteres de password no campo de senha

Tags: html5, css3, senhas

Tenho um formulário simples de usuário e senha, e gostaria de configurar para que ao invés de aparecer o asterisco no campo de senha, queria que aparecesse uma imagem no lugar. A linguagem do *backend* que utilizo é `php 5.6`, para o processamento do formulário, e o *frontend* com `HTML5` e `CSS3`.

Comment: Quando é digitado onde? Qual linguagem de programação você está usando pra construir a interface gráfica?

Comment: Em que linguagem de programação você quer fazer isso? Porque em algumas linguagem isso é limitado.

Comment: Oi desculpe me esqueci disso. A linguagem seria php é um formulário simples de usuário e senha, seria um site construído HTML5 CSS3 com php 5.6 (para a parte de processamento do formulário)

Comment: @JúlioAdolfoRufino Por favor, atente-se à formatação das suas perguntas, deixe um título claro, vá direto ao ponto e, quando fizer uma edição, pode apagar o conteúdo anterior. Não precisa manter um histórico da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode mudar os asteriscos que mascaram o campo padrão de password.

Além disso você nem deve fazer isso porque é o look and feel padrão para mascarar as senhas e você pode na verdade acabar confundindo seus usuários. Acho que não é uma boa prática.